# What happens if I deactivate assert(!_debugLocked);?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I made some code to make flutter-based article board app and
some lines of code made error and below are the codes:

```
class _load_topicsState extends State<load_topics> {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   List<dynamic> topic_received = widget.topic_send;
   List<String> topic_title = [];
   List<String> topic_abstract = [];
   List<String> topic_writer = [];
   List<int> topic_vote_left = [];
   List<int> topic_vote_right = [];

   Future<void> getData() async{
     List<dynamic> topic_all=[];

     for(int i=0; i<topic_received.length;i++)
     {
       FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('topic').doc(topic_received[i].toString()).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc){
         final data_ = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
         String abs = data_['abstract'];
         String title = data_['title'];
         String writer = data_['writer'];
         int vl = data_['vote_left'];
         int vr = data_['vote_right'];
         topic_title.add(title);
         topic_abstract.add(abs);
         topic_writer.add(writer);
         topic_vote_left.add(vl);
         topic_vote_right.add(vr);
       });
     }
     topic_all.add(topic_title);
     topic_all.add(topic_abstract);
     topic_all.add(topic_writer);
     topic_all.add(topic_vote_left);
     topic_all.add(topic_vote_right);

     navi_to_topics(context, topic_all);
     //return topic_all;
   }
   getData();
   return Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       Icon(Icons.downloading,size: 40, color: Colors.amber,),
     ],
   );
 }}
```

I met some error that google firestore does not load data from store fast enough so I forced delaying data load by making load_topic state.

While making a code I confronted error message named :

> E/flutter (20763): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18:
> '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.

I found lots of questions but nothing solved my problem, so I just when to the 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart' and deactivated a line of code.

```
 void _pushEntry(_RouteEntry entry) {
    //assert(!_debugLocked); <--What I deactivated
    assert(() {
      _debugLocked = true;
      return true;
    }());
    assert(entry.route != null);
    assert(entry.route._navigator == null);
    assert(entry.currentState == _RouteLifecycle.push);
    _history.add(entry);
    _flushHistoryUpdates();
    assert(() {
      _debugLocked = false;
      return true;
    }());
    _afterNavigation(entry.route);
  }
```

This solved my problem, but I wonder whether this causes a serious problem soon after.

Can anybody please tell what _debugLocked does and what I did is dangerous or not ?

Comment: Would you please [edit] the question and copy-paste the code that is triggering this error? It looks like you're pushing a new route in the build stage.

Comment: @lepsch I editted my question. Thanks

Comment: What does `navi_to_topics` do?

Comment: navi_to_topics passes the `List<dynamic> topic_all` to other state B. The state B makes the list of card according to the data of topic_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `Navigator.push` during the build stage. To fix it make sure you call `getData` in the `initState` of the widget instead so it's called just once when the widget initializes.

It's going to be like the following:

```dart
class _load_topicsState extends State<load_topics> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData().then((topicAll) => navi_to_topics(context, topicAll));
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
    List<dynamic> topicAll = [];
    List<dynamic> topicReceived = widget.topic_send;
    List<String> topicTitle = [];
    List<String> topicAbstract = [];
    List<String> topicWriter = [];
    List<int> topicVoteLeft = [];
    List<int> topicVoteRight = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < topicReceived.length; i++) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('topic')
          .doc(topicReceived[i].toString())
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        final data_ = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        String abs = data_['abstract'];
        String title = data_['title'];
        String writer = data_['writer'];
        int vl = data_['vote_left'];
        int vr = data_['vote_right'];
        topicTitle.add(title);
        topicAbstract.add(abs);
        topicWriter.add(writer);
        topicVoteLeft.add(vl);
        topicVoteRight.add(vr);
      });
    }
    topicAll.add(topicTitle);
    topicAll.add(topicAbstract);
    topicAll.add(topicWriter);
    topicAll.add(topicVoteLeft);
    topicAll.add(topicVoteRight);

    return topicAll;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Icon(
          Icons.downloading,
          size: 40,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems your code works well. Can you please tell me what `iniState()` does? Im veeery new to flutter so I think I don't exactly get why this works. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Have a look at this article about [Widget Lifecycle in Flutter](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-widget-lifecycle-in-flutter-e36031c697d0). The short answer is that `initState()` is called once right after the widget is created.